# Overflow in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing Harris corner detection and having overflow error:

```
harris.py:27: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
  Mat[0][1]=Ix[i][j]*Iy[i][j]
harris.py:28: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
  Mat[1][0]=Ix[i][j]*Iy[i][j]
```

This is the whole source code. Where does the error come from? Since Ix.max is 255 and min is 0.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im=cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

(M,N)=im.shape
print M
print N

Gx=np.array([[1, 0, -1],[ 2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
Gy=np.array([[1, 2, 1],[0, 0, 0],[-1, -2, -1]])

Ix=cv2.filter2D(im, -1, Gx)
Iy=cv2.filter2D(im, -1, Gy)

print np.max(Ix)
print np.min(Ix)
print np.max(Iy)
print np.min(Iy)

Mat=np.zeros((2,2), dtype='float64')
R=np.zeros((M,N), dtype='float64')
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        Mat[0][0]=Ix[i][j]**2
        Mat[0][1]=Ix[i][j]*Iy[i][j]
        Mat[1][0]=Ix[i][j]*Iy[i][j]
        Mat[1][1]=Iy[i][j]**2

        R[i][j]=np.linalg.det(Mat)-(np.matrix.trace(Mat))**2


cv2.imshow("Ix",Ix)
cv2.imshow("Iy",Iy)
cv2.imshow("R",R)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that your input data is `uint8`.  Because you're multiplying two `uint8`'s, the result is a `uint8`, even though it will be upcasted when you assign it to an item in the float array `Mat`.

As an example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.uint8(255) * np.uint8(255)
./anaconda/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
Out[2]: 1
```

Notice that numpy will happily return the result (`1`), but it's not what you might expect if you're not familiar with limited-precision integers.

Newer versions of numpy raise a runtime warning, while older versions with allow it to happen silently.

This is deliberate behavior.  It's *very* useful when dealing with large arrays. You just have to be aware that numpy behaves similar to C when it comes to limited-precision data types.

You have several options.

1. Cast your entire input array to floating point (e.g. `Ix, Iy = Ix.astype(float), Iy.astype(float)`.
2. Cast `Ix[i][j]` and `Iy[i][j]` to floats inside the loop.

Comment: A possibly better way to do this is to explicitly call the `np.multiply` function.  Then you can specify the output dtype like so: `np.multiply(Ix[i][j], Iy[i][j], dtype=np.float64)`.  You can also preallocate an array of the correct type and use the `out=` form of `np.multiply`.